# Animating a glow in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to achieve a pulsating glow effect in raphael.js. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/eaPSC/ I'm very sorry about the massive brain. ;)

I tried animating both the width of the glow effect and the opacity and neither seem to be influenced by animation at all. (The glow is static. I examined it by hiding the brain element, zooming in and checking out just the glow element, and there is simply no action.)

I tried animating a separate (non-glow) element using the same procedure and multiple attributes do get animated fine.

thanks!

Comment: @ShawnChin thanks, I took a Creative-Commons SVG brain from wikipedia and cleaned it up a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot animate the width or color properties of a glow. The glow is created by adding a stroke to a set of paths with zero fill. If you want to change the color or the width of the glow you have to animate the stroke or stroke-width properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/eaPSC/2/

**Wrong:** (quoted from your source):

```
  anim = Raphael.animation({
    width: 15,
    opeacity: 1
  }, 500);
```

**Slightly More Correct:**

```
  anim = Raphael.animation({
    "stroke-width": 15,
    opacity: 1
  }, 500);
```

But you will notice that this kills off the gradiented glow effect. If you actually look at the source code for glow() you can see that the final for loop creates a layered set of paths to create the gradient effect.

```
 elproto.glow = function (glow) {
    if (this.type == "text") {
        return null;
    }
    glow = glow || {};
    var s = {
        width: (glow.width || 10) + (+this.attr("stroke-width") || 1),
        fill: glow.fill || false,
        opacity: glow.opacity || .5,
        offsetx: glow.offsetx || 0,
        offsety: glow.offsety || 0,
        color: glow.color || "#000"
    },
        c = s.width / 2,
        r = this.paper,
        out = r.set(),
        path = this.realPath || getPath[this.type](this);
    path = this.matrix ? mapPath(path, this.matrix) : path;
    for (var i = 1; i < c + 1; i++) {
        out.push(r.path(path).attr({
            stroke: s.color,
            fill: s.fill ? s.color : "none",
            "stroke-linejoin": "round",
            "stroke-linecap": "round",
            "stroke-width": +(s.width / c * i).toFixed(3),
            opacity: +(s.opacity / c).toFixed(3)
        }));
    }
    return out.insertBefore(this).translate(s.offsetx, s.offsety);
};
```

So if you just fix the stroke-width for all of these paths, it kills the glow effect as you will see in the example. There isn't really an easy answer to this. You could possibly animate it yourself using setInterval to remove the old glow and add a new one with a new width, but it doesn't sound like a very efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

i've been able to correct this issue without the timing issue as shown in your jsfiddle demo by adding the following to resume.

```
elproto.resume = function (anim) {
    for (var i = 0; i < animationElements.length; i++) if (animationElements[i].el.id == this.id && (!anim || animationElements[i].anim == anim)) {
        var e = animationElements[i];
        if (eve("raphael.anim.resume." + this.id, this, e.anim) !== false) {

            delete e.paused;
            this.status(e.anim, e.status,**e.totalOrigin**);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, will test this in a couple of hours and accept this answer if it looks pulsey :)

Comment: hey Ben, I'm trying to test this without editing the raphael source. Could I overwrite my objects' prototype instead? Would it be the brain's, the animation's or the glow's prototype?